# How to attach a camera to fill a mobile's screen without zoom-in?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, adobe

I have a flex video capturing mobile application that attaches its camera to a UIComponent as follows:

```
 var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
 camera.setQuality(0,100);

 video = new Video(width, height);
 video.attachCamera(camera);

 var uiVideo:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
 uiVideo.width = video.width;
 uiVideo.height = video.height;
 uiVideo.addChild(video);
 videoGroup.addElement(uiVideo);
```

*width and height are the mobile's screen size.

The problem with the above code is the video/camera the user sees when recording is zoomed-in when compared with the recorded video. That happens probably because, a camera with dimensions 20x30 is streched to a screen size of 60x90, thus resulting in a zoom of 3x.

How can I avoid that?

Is there a way to strech a camera to fill the mobile screen without zooming-in (distortion is okay, when the screen's ratio is different from the camera's ratio)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Camera.setMode()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setMode%28%29)? You can pass in width, height, frames per second, and a 4th parameter. If the camera does not support that resolution you specify, it will try to use a supported resolution that is similar.